# How to extract audio after particular sound?

Tags: python, audio, scipy, librosa

Let's say I have a few very long audio files (for ex., radio recordings). I need to extract 5 seconds after particular sound (for ex., ad start sound) from each file. Each file may contain 3-5 such sounds, so I should get *(3-5)*number of source files* result files.

I found [librosa](https://pypi.org/project/librosa/) and [scipy](https://medium.com/@almeidneto/sound-pattern-recognition-with-python-9aff69edce5d) python libraries, but not sure if they can help. What should I start with?

Answer (score 0):

You could start by calculating the correlation of the signal with your particular sound. Not sure if librosa offers this. I'd start with [scipy.signal.correlate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate.html) or [scipy.signal.convolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html).

Not sure what your background is. Start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) if you need some theory.

Basically the correlation will be high if the audio matches your particular signal or is very similar to it. After identifying these positions you can select an area around them.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. If sounds are identical, do I really need to use correlation-based methods?

Comment: You mean really really identical down to the last byte? It is probably still the best way.